# Why isn't my new state hitting my component's render method?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have redux and react working correctly I believe and I have a child component firing off an action which then makes it as a new state to the parent component's `mapStatetoDispatch` method. However, while I can confirm through the console log that this state is indeed new, it never hits the render method (the props come back as undefined, just as they did before when there was no props to send down to them).

I must be missing something fundamental, I even tried all the component update or next state methods. Here is my component:

https://gist.github.com/geoffreysmith/ff909437a29ae8ab8db8038276b4f3b2

Thank you!

Edit: Here is my reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer as routing } from 'react-router-redux'
import { ADD_NEW_REPORT } from '../actions/Dashboard';


function reports(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_NEW_REPORT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { [action.index]: addReport(undefined, action) })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function addReport(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_NEW_REPORT:
            return {
                 index: action.index,
                 siteAddress: action.siteAddress,
                 receivedAt: action.receivedAt,
                 status: action.status
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
    }

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  reports,
  routing
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: What does your reducer look like?  The most common cause for a component not updating is accidental mutation of data in a reducer, per http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering . Although since you say the "props are undefined", that may not be the issue here.  Still would help to see your state shape.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `mapStateToProps` should return an object (the `props`).

So I would change it to this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    reports: state.reports
  }
}
```